# Function in prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

A have a make target `foo/%.bar`. It matches files like:

`foo/x/y/z.bar`
`foo/a.bar`

Now, I want a prerequisite `prereq.o` which must reside in the same folder than the `.bar` file. Thus, for `foo/x/y/z.bar` the prerequisite should be `foo/x/y/prereq.o`, for `foo/a.bar` it should be `foo/prereq.o`.

How to achieve this?

I tried using the `dir` function like this:

`foo/%.bar : foo/$(dir %)prereq.o`

However, this does not work because functions are evaluated before the patterns are expanded. So how does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use [`.SECONDEXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo/%.bar : foo/$$(dir %)prereq.o
    @echo $@ $<
```

The `$$` in `$$(dir...)` is necessary so that it is not evaluated until the second expansion occurs.